# How can I get python to use css <![if !IE> correctly

Tags: python, html, css, cgi

I am trying to create a dynamic page that has to do some work behind the scene/server side and also show a web page where the person can retrieve what we have processed server side. So just as a base template for a page I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, os, sys, commands

print "Content-type: text/html\n";

print "<html>\n"
print "<head>\n"
print "<title>My Title Here</title>\n"

#Need to find out how to get python to get css code done. 
print "<![if !IE]>  <link href="../styles/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> <![endif]>\n"

print "</head>\n"
print "<body>\n"
print "<body>\n"
print "</html>\n"
```

This line `print "<![if !IE]>  <link href="../styles/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> <![endif]>\n"` Is the one causing problems. How does one use this logical way of finding out and using the css when the page is built in python then served to the user? How do I incorporate css in my pages when done through python?

Comment: You have to use single quotes `'` around a string if the string contains double quotes `"`.

Comment: Note that only the first `print` statement requires the `\n` at the end (since the headers must be separated from the content by a blank line). The remainder will be perfectly OK with simply the `\n` that the `print` statement automatically adds. You could also look into using triple quotes, to allow you to more easily include quotes in your content.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
print '<![if !IE]>  <link href="../styles/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> <![endif]>\n'
```